# How to obtain Description & Url from Url Field via Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest

I have a problem with retrieving the Description from an Url Field via the Rest Api from SharePoint.

If I make a call and select an Url Field with the normal $select

> _api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items(1)?$select=FolderUrl

It retrieves automatically the Url Value from the Url Field.

So I have tried to do it with a Expand:

> _api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items(1)?$select=FolderUrl/Description&$expand=FolderUrl

But that query doesn't work.

So how can I obtain the Description Information from a Url Field via the Rest API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use URL

> _api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items(1)?$select=FolderUrl

You will get two properties

1. d:Description
2. d:Url

So you don't need to expand

```
<m:properties><d:FolderUrl m:type="SP.FieldUrlValue"><d:Description>Google Description</d:Description><d:Url>http://google.com</d:Url></d:FolderUrl></m:properties>
```